# How do I make a UIViewController Library Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a number of published iOS apps and I am trying to add some extra functionality to most of them which would be the same, so I would like to use the same code.

The apps all produce some results which the user might want to email, save or export as a .txt file.

I want to create a class which can be access by more than one ViewController within each app (not at the same time) by sending it a message. The new class with then create an actionsheet giving the options and then handle whichever option is selected.

I can do all of this by adding the code within each ViewController in each app but I'm struggling to do things the right way i.e. reuse code!

Because my handler class has to deal with UIActionSheet, MFMailComposeViewController, UIAlertView and more, I think I'm right in thinking that it must be a subclass of UIViewController. Is this correct?

Do I need to make it a delegate?

I'm trying to do things the right way instead of the way that just works, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like what you want is a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on UIViewController.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are looking for to add functionality to existing classes is [Objective-C categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: I do have another quick question which I have been trying to resolve since your last post. How do I pass data back from the clickedButtonAtIndex method to the UIViewController?

Comment: In your category, in the implementation of the method that creates and presents the alert view, action sheet, etc., assign the delegate to self. Then, in the view controller that calls your category method, override the appropriate delegate call back and do the work appropriate for how that controller wants to handle the given action. If you're seeing a warning when you assign the delegate, you want to cast self like so (id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)self.